# How do you calculate the voltage between two phases?

Tags: voltage, phase

If I have two hot wires at given voltages and phases (for example 120v 0deg and 120v 120deg), how do I calculate the voltage between the two wires?

Comment: You know the equations that define the voltage of each phase, simply subtract the voltage of one phase from the other.

Comment: ...or, to get a better understanding of *why* you're getting the answer you are, try graphing both waveforms for 2-3 cycles & look at the graphs. It often helps these things make more sense when you can see them graphicaly represented.

Comment: Phasors are your friend.

Comment: oops, i was adding them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have to think about this as vectors...

[image]

With a little trigonometry you can calculate the length of the hypotenuse as..

\$=\sqrt{(Sin(\Theta).V)^2 + (V(1-Cos(\Theta)))^2}\$

Comment: For simple 3-phase supplies, the phase-phase voltage conveniently works out at √3 times the phase-neutral voltage.